# How to make Kile's spell checker ignore comments and \todo?

Tags: editors, kile, spelling

I use Kile as my Latex editor. I really like Kile, but one of the things that I do find unbearable is the fact that does not seem to be a line or a command to force the spell checker to ignore a certain piece of text, like a \todo{text} tag written in a foreign language.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's indeed the case that you cannot do this through Kile. Spellchecking is done by the editor component itself, which happens to be Kate Part. If text parts should not be spell checked, then you have to modify your latex.xml file.

The details were initially posted [here](http://kate-editor.org/2009/07/08/followup-on-kates-on-the-fly-spellchecking/). How to write or modify your syntax highlighting file is described in detail [here](http://docs.kde.org/stable/en/applications/kate/katehighlight-xml-format.html). In short, you could add a rule that matches \todo{ that switches into another context. In this context, use itemDatas for which you set spellChecking="false". When you detect the character '}', #pop the context again.

Similarly, looking at my latex.xml, the itemData "Comments" already has the attribute spellChecking="false". So maybe you can also get a newer latex.xml hightlighting file or your distribution/Kile.